# Zeus Yocto build linux cpp application development

Tags: sdk, embedded-linux, yocto, zeus

for the `zeus` release of `yocto` there is plug-in support for `eclipse` to develop applications. Can anyone help to how to set up `eclipse` for cross-compile the code?
Presently I have installed the standard `sdk` on my `pc`. I need to know how to set up `eclipse` to cross-compile using the `sdk`.

Regards,
Srinu

Comment: Try following this https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.1.2/adt-manual/adt-manual.html#adt-eclipse

Comment: Hi, Thank you soo much for the reply. Presently i am using the yocto zeus release(3.0). Whatever you provided is for very old version. In the new yocto manual documentation says ADT support for new versions of eclipse is removed. Can you help me with new version of Eclipse. If extendable sdk is the presently only new option then please provide information on how to use with newer version of eclipse.

Comment: I never worked with the Eclipse SDK, I only found the guide. If they stopped supporting Eclipse at some point then I don't know if there is a simple way to do this. Look at the guide for your Yocto version. I guess you can always try to download an older version of Eclipse, but I don't know if this is something you want to do.